# Prevent users from submitting a form multiple times by pressing the ENTER button

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, forms

I am using the following code to prevent users from submitting the form more than once. It will hide the submit button and make a hidden div visible with a 'Please wait' text.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

$('#form_id').on('submit', function(evt) {

    $('#submit_button_id').hide();
    $('#hidden_div_id').show();

});


});
```

However, the above code only works when users click on submit button.
If they press ENTER repeatedly, the form will be submitted multiple times.

Is there a way to prevent users from pressing ENTER more than once when form is submitted?

Comment: Check the keycode of evt of your form submit, if it equals the Enter key, return false.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the following inside the submit event and it seems to do the job:

         $('form input').on('keypress', function(e) {
         return e.which !== 13;
         });


Is this the correct way to do it or is there a better way?

Comment: That's the best way I know. Maybe someone else has a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only allow it to submit once.

```
$('#form_id').on('submit', function() {
    $(this).on('submit', function() {
        return false;
    });

    $('#submit_button_id').hide();
    $('#hidden_div_id').show();
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this one works better. Will it work on all browsers?

Comment: It should, this is just an event listener that creates another event listener to send false after the first time.